# Why git stash apply command does not work?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have run git stash, when I am upgrading flutter. Now I am trying to run "git stash apply" command, but I get this error.
This is really important to me because it has been a lot of progress since my last commit.
Is there anyone who knows what can I do? Thanks for your suggestions.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

````
    git stash apply stash^{/0e55629}
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
        ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
        lib/snapi_data/doctor.dart
        linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
        macos/Flutter/Flutter-Debug.xcconfig
        macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig
        macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
        pubspec.lock
        pubspec.yaml
        windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
        modified:   ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
        modified:   lib/snapi_data/doctor.dart
        modified:   linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        modified:   linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
        modified:   macos/Flutter/Flutter-Debug.xcconfig
        modified:   macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig
        modified:   macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
        modified:   pubspec.lock
        modified:   pubspec.yaml
        modified:   windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        modified:   windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vscode/
        android/app/google-services.json
        android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/medicte_/
        ios/Podfile
        ios/Podfile.lock
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/100.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/1024.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/114.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/120.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/128.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/144.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/152.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/16.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/167.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/172.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/180.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/196.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/20.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/216.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/256.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/29.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/32.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/40.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/48.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/50.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/512.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/55.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/57.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/58.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/60.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/64.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/72.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/76.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/80.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/87.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/88.png
        lib/assets/
        lib/cards/
        lib/firebase_options.dart
        lib/images/102642-contact.json
        lib/images/81732-contact-us.json
        lib/images/96769-contac-mouse-web.json
        lib/images/Lovepik_com-401792159-medical-robot.png
        lib/images/address.png
        lib/images/alarm-alert-bell-notification-icon-89422.png
        lib/images/email.png
        lib/images/facebook.png
        lib/images/instagram.png
        lib/images/lf20_9gwslqtn.json
        lib/images/notification.png
        lib/images/telephone-call.png
        lib/images/twitter.png
        lib/pages/category_page.dart
        lib/pages/chat_ui.dart
        lib/pages/doctor_page.dart
        lib/pages/doctor_search_page.dart
        lib/pages/hospital_page.dart
        lib/pages/treatment_page.dart
        lib/snapi_data/hospital.dart
        lib/snapi_data/treatments.dart
        macos/Podfile

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
❯ git stash apply
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
        ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
        lib/snapi_data/doctor.dart
        linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
        macos/Flutter/Flutter-Debug.xcconfig
        macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig
        macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
        pubspec.lock
        pubspec.yaml
        windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
        modified:   ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
        modified:   lib/snapi_data/doctor.dart
        modified:   linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        modified:   linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
        modified:   macos/Flutter/Flutter-Debug.xcconfig
        modified:   macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig
        modified:   macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
        modified:   pubspec.lock
        modified:   pubspec.yaml
        modified:   windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
        modified:   windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vscode/
        android/app/google-services.json
        android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/medicte_/
        ios/Podfile
        ios/Podfile.lock
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/100.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/1024.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/114.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/120.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/128.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/144.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/152.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/16.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/167.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/172.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/180.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/196.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/20.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/216.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/256.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/29.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/32.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/40.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/48.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/50.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/512.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/55.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/57.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/58.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/60.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/64.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/72.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/76.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/80.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/87.png
        ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/88.png
        lib/assets/
        lib/cards/
        lib/firebase_options.dart
        lib/images/102642-contact.json
        lib/images/81732-contact-us.json
        lib/images/96769-contac-mouse-web.json
        lib/images/Lovepik_com-401792159-medical-robot.png
        lib/images/address.png
        lib/images/alarm-alert-bell-notification-icon-89422.png
        lib/images/email.png
        lib/images/facebook.png
        lib/images/instagram.png
        lib/images/lf20_9gwslqtn.json
        lib/images/notification.png
        lib/images/telephone-call.png
        lib/images/twitter.png
        lib/pages/category_page.dart
        lib/pages/chat_ui.dart
        lib/pages/doctor_page.dart
        lib/pages/doctor_search_page.dart
        lib/pages/hospital_page.dart
        lib/pages/treatment_page.dart
        lib/snapi_data/hospital.dart
        lib/snapi_data/treatments.dart
        macos/Podfile

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a"```
````

Comment: You need to commit current changes and then you can merge other commit to current commits. If you have any changes which is not committed and you are trying to merge other commits then it will throw same error i.e. during stash apply/pop, merge, pull, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-stash%5D+error%3A+Your+local+changes+to+the+following+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge